# COCOS2DX libpng Google Play Notification June 2016

Tags: android, google-play, cocos2d-x, libpng, android-security

I have received notification on my many apps on Google Play all developed in **COCOS2DX**, the Notification states that there is a **security vulnerability in libpng**, I am sure this is in cocos2dX because I haven't received them on games developed in AndEngine or Unity.
We are using **COCOS2DX version 2.2, 2.1.2 and 2.2.6** and we need to fix this ASAP
Can any one suggest a solution for this problem? We cannot move to new COCOS2dX Version because we have many game so we need to fix the old version.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a fix, and that is to extract the following zip file into your “cocos2dx\platform\third_party\android\prebuilt” folder:

Download the fix from here:
[libpng_fix.zip for Cocos2d-x 2.x](http://bengigi.com/wp-content/uploads/libpng_fix.zip)

And change “Android.mk” file under “cocos2dx” folder:

Change:
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos_libpng_static

to
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos_libzlib_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_libpng_static

Change:
$(call import-module,libpng)

to:
$(call import-module,libzlib)
$(call import-module,libpng)

courtesy: [Bengigi Apps and Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6507331239206693428)

Comment: I think you may missed the link: http://bengigi.com/wp-content/uploads/libpng_fix.zip
And I think it won't be a bad idea to compile it yourself: https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android

Comment: the above solution has been tested and it is working.

Comment: Thanks @JawadAmjad it works me too, one thing i noted on changing android.mk file we should keep order same that mentioned above otherwise it give errors.

Answer (score 1):

here two solution:

http://www.bengigi.com/cocos2d-x-2-x-android-libpng-vulnerability-fix/

http://xiao.terrygo.win/2016/06/17/Google-Play-warnings/

new version libpng need zlib. so you need update libpng and add zlib needed.